# Proper way to get page content

Tags: pages, query, post-content

I have to get specific page content (like page(12))

I used that :

```
  <?php $id=47; $post = get_page($id); echo $post->post_content;  ?>
```

Work nice execpt for compatibility with qtranslate it return french and english text

But  the loop is fine, return only the good language version

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="post">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div> <!-- .post -->
```

So the question.... HOW to get a specific page content insite the loop...

Comment: This was very helpful! Thanks! I had a hard time looking for what I thought was a simple request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution i have founs that work fine...the codex should be more specific about the apply_filter ... used it all everytime

```
$id=47;
$post = get_page($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
```

But i have found a great place to ask question (HERE)! thanks guys !

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify:

You mixed two things here. qTranslate stores the different languages in the same post. If you call `get_content()`, `$post->content` or an other direct query, you will get the whole content with all different languages from the database.

What qTranslates do, it creates a filter-hook which is attached to `the_content` hook. If somebody call `the_content()` in a page template, all other languages will be filtered out.

So you're right. To filter the other languages, you have to apply the filter-hook `the_content` to your output.

Answer (score 5):

It's not used often, but myself I like [`get_post_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field) function. It is compact, yet flexible for when you need to pull single specific field.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `get_page`, like so:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page